# Matlab uses too much memory

Tags: matlab

I am using Matlab do run some evaluations and then I want to save the struct where the results are saved, for future use.
**Problem:** The first thing I have noticed was that the execution lasted too long, maybe 8hours, then when I wanted to save the struct maybe further 2hours. After several blocking and redoing the process, I finally managed to save a copy of the data. What I find it confusing is that the file is 150GB big.
**Process:** The code structure goes as follows: It iterates over *.csv files* in a folder (50 000), it reads them in as csv format files, extracts the needed columns and calculates the data.
**My view:** I guess, the whole iteration and extracting data from each file takes a lot of cache, which could slow the process down, as the time goes!? But, I still don't undestand why the final *.mat* file takes so much memory, since in the past for the same data, but different parameters, it didn't need that much space to save the results.
**Question/s:** Is it possible to reduce the size of the final file, without affecting the results? I base this question on the assumption that matlab is maybe saving additional information from the process?
**Code Schema:**

```
    clc; close all; clear all; fclose('all');
result = struct('values_a', [], 'other', []);

counter = 1;
for i=1:length(dataNames)
        try
        structRead = ezread(nameOfFile, ',');
        values_a = structRead.timestamp;

        for j=1:length(values_a)
            if(strcmp(values_a(j),'N'))
                if(j==1)
                    values_a(j) = values_a(j+1);
                elseif (j==length(values_a))
                    values_a(j) = values_a(j-1);
                else
                    values_a(j) = (values_a(j-1)+values_a(j+1))/2;
                end
            end
            result(counter).values_a(j) = values_a(j);
        end
        counter=counter+1;

    catch
        counterFailed= counterFailed+1;
    end

    end
end

    save(path2save,'result','-v7.3');
```

Comment: Save less data, use less disk space... Your calculation might take hours because MATLAB has to page the results to disk, because your RAM isn't large enough to store the intermediate steps in memory. Process your data in sections, save it in sections, I'd wager your 50,000 CSV files have a large combined file size?? This question is too broad as-is

Comment: they total 20GB

Comment: This needs a [mcve] to be able to debug. If we dont have example values (not the real ones, examples) we can not debug

Comment: I cant post the code due to company privacy. That is why I posted a schema. I try to understand the root of the problem, debugging will be much easier then. That is why I have written my assumption, hoping that it will be either corrected, if wrong, or propsed a solution if correct. :)

Comment: We can only speculate based on what you've given us. Nobody is asking you to post private "company code", we're asking for a [mcve]. File size is dependent on data types, variable types, how much data you're storing etc. You should be able to create a dummy example which paints a picture, perhaps making a 1kB CSV file into a 100kB MAT file with the same settings and processing you're using, ergo demonstrating the issue. This will inevitably help you debug your issue and probably see the root cause yourself.

Comment: What is `nameOfFile` in the code? It’s not defined anywhere. Are you sure you are reading in each file only once? How does `ezread` transform the data in the files? Did you step through your program with a debugger to ensure it runs as you expect it to?

Comment: One way to speed it up is to move the assignment `result(counter).values_a(j) = values_a(j);` our of the loop: `result(counter).values_a = values_a;`